# Set Header in the web service server side java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapheader

I have a web service client which adds a soap header in the request message.

In the web service server side I access this header and validate the message, but I need to send parameters in the soap header of the response message. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: See this link: http://devplace.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/adding-soap-header-in-java/

Comment: This link show how to add header in the soap envelope for the request, but i need add header in the soap envolope for the response.